# Accountmanager vs sharedpreference for authentication and server communication

Tags: android, http, authentication, sharedpreferences, accountmanager

In my project want to read and write the data in server depends upon the authentication key(user).

So far I planned to use shared preference to store user authentication key for further communication with server.

Later I came to know "Account manager" by reading [this tutorial](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/):

I have little confuse to use account manager or sharedpreference.

I feel little difficult to understand accountmanager.

Can any one guide which method suits for my project.

Any tutorial for account manager.?

Any other suggestions...?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend you to think about your requirement first. If authentication is like google+, Facebook and Twitter then I would suggest you to use [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

**AccountManager**: This centralized registry of user's online account. Account Manager is capable of storing the `OAuth` token and does the job for all Google Apps in Android.

**SharedPreferences**:This is for storing and retrieving small range of data for more [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: Though I am using Private account for user only  for this application. **Shared preferences** is an solution.

Comment: r u using any auth token? What happen if user changes password on another client? If u need to manage this all then U should user Account Manager else SharedPreferences is good

Comment: The answer above seems not matching http://stackoverflow.com/a/10890978/3286489, which discourage one to use AccountManager unless one need syncAdapter

Comment: @Elye this answer for the above question. I don't know the context which you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Shared Preference. Its easy and effective as well. Read the documentation to know about Shared Preference. Presonally I have used it in many application and it comes really handy.